# how get recursive parent in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, tree, parent

i have bellow structure of rows it must show all ancestors of Special Row

---

```
id | parent_id
-------------
1  |  null
2  |   1
3  |  null
4  |   2
5  |   4
```

i will write simple query but not work

```
select * from table1 as a
join table1 as b on (a.parent_id = b.id )
where a.id = 4
```

========================

Desired output:

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have any builtin "hierarchical" tools.  You need to write a `SELECT` in a loop, either in your application code, or in a Stored Procedure.